# selenium open Chrome,than not execute next programe

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser =  webdriver.Chrome('/Users/xinmei/Documents/program/python/seleniumproject/    webdrivers/chromedriver')
print("start")
browser.get('http://www.yahoo.com')
print("get")
assert 'Yahoo!' in browser.title

elem = browser.find_element_by_name('p')  # Find the search box
elem.send_keys('seleniumhq' + Keys.RETURN)

browser.quit()
```

browser =  webdriver.Chrome('/Users/xinmei/Documents/program/python/seleniumproject/    webdrivers/chromedriver')

open my chrome browser,than "start" won't be printed,programe sleep here,why?

Comment: You'd better choose another browser. You'll not be able to execute `Keys.RETURN` in Chrome anyway

Comment: driver = webdriver.Firefox()

Comment: Yeah,Firefox is fine,but why chrome not work here?